# Scala concurrency problem for transactions system

Tags: scala, concurrency, jvm, akka, actor

I am trying to build a transactions system using `scala`. I am using `akka-http` as the server and rest of work is performed by plain classes and methods as of now.

The steps are :

- Read balance from account.
- Do some processing(take for example taking loans from other linked account).
- Update balance to account(deduct the amount).

When we fire multiple transactions for same account concurrently some of them read stale balance at step 1. Because 1st transaction is yet to update balance.

*Ideally all `read/update` operations to some account should happen sequentially irrespective of the api call.*

I tried to make actor for account so that all messages are executed in a sequence to actor.
But in that case reading from account is painful as ask pattern(?) also returns `Future[Any]` not `Future[SomeAccountDetailsObject]`.

Even if it may work by parsing from `.asInstanceOf[Future[SomeAccountDetailsObject]]` and I will have to manage and pass `Future` in further code which I tend to ignore as I have to read from various linked accounts in a transaction and also it is a legacy code so I want to touch it as less as possible.

**Is there any possible way to tackle this problem and even better if using akka stack by isolating the effects of new code for account operations as just a method call or something**

Comment: Are you using akka typed or akka classic?  With typed, you shouldn't get a `Future[Any]`.

Comment: A side remark, when you'll be reading the read response you can't be sure whether the balance didn't change already in the meantime.

Comment: @LeviRamsey Its akka classic.

Comment: I would suggest dont use Future in this case because I dont understand how the dataflow is handled.

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get an answer without including example code.  But in general, once state is in an actor, you can only interact with it via messages (which tends to imply `Future` when outside an actor (e.g. when in a tream processing an http request)).

Comment: So with that, the best I can advise is that if you want to make this transactional, you should put the three steps you listed into an actor which is effectively managing the saga you've outlined.  The `pipeTo` operation will be helpful for unwrapping futures within the actor.